# HTTPMethod and HTTPBody properties not found on NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to create a POST request. I am creating a custom URL but when I try and print out values I get the following errors:

EDIT:

```
(lldb) po request.HTTPBody
error: property 'HTTPBody' not found on object of type 'NSMutableURLRequest *'

(lldb) po request.HTTPMethod
error: property 'HTTPMethod' not found on object of type 'NSMutableURLRequest *'
```

Here is my code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&serviceTicket=%@&tags=%@&tags=%@",taskId,fullName,@"test1"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webUrl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webUrl]];
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Xcode must just be confused. Make sure you're using the latest version. Quit and relaunch Xcode. The code above compiled for me after defining taskId, fullName, and webUrl.

Comment: Thanks, the code compiles fine for me as well - but when I set a break point and then try and print out the values for the above is when it shows up as an error - sorry if that wasn't clear before. I am using the latest Xcode.

Comment: In that case, you should update the question with what you are typing in the console. Good luck.

Comment: I wonder if it's having trouble with the getter syntax.  Does `po [request HTTPBody]` give the same result?

Comment: @PhillipMills - Actually that works, I am able to see the body now! Weird... Thanks!

Comment: Not an expert...but I think it's related to `po` being a synonym for a lldb command that has a specific language expectation.